# java try/catch problems I want to catch ints entered in a string option

Tags: java

Kind of stuck with this question but how I can I make my try catch to only allow strings into the input box. (the relevant code is towards the bottom here sorry about the messy format still quite new to graphical programming) I thought my code below would work however I guess it doesn't and I am not quite sure on now to make it catch for all ints in the sting input as the ints there are being entered as strings. Also if you could look at the email try/catch as well pop up the error box as well if a @ sign is up in since it is somewhat similar. Thanks

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;

import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;


public class MainPanel extends JPanel {

    Player myPlayer;
    Player myOtherPlayer;
    private int WIDTH = 1000;
    private int HEIGHT = 1000;
    private int WALLWIDTH = 100;
    private int WALLHEIGHT = 100;
    private ArrayList<Wall> walls = new ArrayList<Wall>();
    String Name;
    String Email;
    int favNum;

    Timer myTimer = new Timer(500, new timerListener());    
    JLabel myTimeLabel;
    int time =1;



    public MainPanel()
    {
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDTH,HEIGHT));
        JLabel myLabel= new JLabel ("Game ends once 30 seconds is receahed:");
        myLabel.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD,32));
        myLabel.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        myTimeLabel= new JLabel (Integer.toString(time));
        myTimeLabel.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD,32));
        myTimer.start();

        add(myLabel);
        add(myTimeLabel);
        myPlayer = new Player(0,100, "toad.png", KeyEvent.VK_UP, KeyEvent.VK_DOWN, KeyEvent.VK_LEFT, KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT,this, 50, 38);
        myOtherPlayer = new Player(200,200, "toad.png", KeyEvent.VK_W, KeyEvent.VK_S, KeyEvent.VK_A, KeyEvent.VK_D,this, 50, 38);
        createWalls();




    }

    public ArrayList<Wall> getWalls() {
        return walls;
    }

    public void createWalls()
    {
        int j = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < HEIGHT/WALLHEIGHT; i++)
        {
            for(int k = 0; k < WIDTH/WALLWIDTH; k++)
            {
                if(i == 0 || i == (HEIGHT/WALLHEIGHT-1))
                {
                    walls.add(new Wall(k*WALLWIDTH,j,"road.png", 100, 100));
                }

            }
            j+=WALLHEIGHT;
        }
    }


    private class timerListener implements ActionListener
    {


        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            time++;
            myTimeLabel.setText(Integer.toString(time));
            myTimeLabel.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
            if(time == 31)
            {
                myTimer.stop();
            }
            repaint();
        }

    }


    public void paintComponent(Graphics page)
    {
        super.paintComponent(page);

        page.drawImage(myPlayer.getImageIcon().getImage(), myPlayer.getX(), myPlayer.getY(), null);
        page.drawImage(myOtherPlayer.getImageIcon().getImage(), myOtherPlayer.getX(), myOtherPlayer.getY(), null);


        for(int i = 0; i < walls.size(); i++)
        {
            page.drawImage(walls.get(i).getImageIcon().getImage(), walls.get(i).getX(), walls.get(i).getY(), null);


        }

        page.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN,32)); 
        page.drawString("Player 1 Score: " + myPlayer.getScore(), 100, 800);
        page.drawString("Player 2 Score: " + myOtherPlayer.getScore(), 100, 850);
        myPlayer.checkOffScreen();

        if(time == 5)
        {
            page.drawString("GAME OVER", WIDTH/2-100, HEIGHT/2);



            try{
                Name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is your name?");
                }catch (NumberFormatException  e) {
                    if (!Name.matches("^[a-z][a-z ]*[a-z]?$")){
                    JOptionPane.showInputDialog("You entered a number, this only accepts alphabetical letters. Please enter your name");}
                }

            try{
                favNum= Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is your favorite number?")); 
                }catch (NumberFormatException  e) {

                JOptionPane.showInputDialog("You entered a text, this only accepts numbers . Please enter your  favorite number");}

            try{
                Email =JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter your email");
                }catch (InputMismatchException  e) {
                JOptionPane.showInputDialog("You enter your email incorrectly. Please include an @ sign with it");}
                }

            }

    }
```

Comment: Put your closing brackets on newlines, good habit to start now.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is create an isInteger method...

```
protected static boolean isInteger(String s) {
    try {
        Integer.parseInt(s);
    } catch(NumberFormatException e) {
        return false;
    } catch(NullPointerException e) {
        return false;
    }
    // String can be changed into an integer
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What I am getting from your code is : you want to make sure user inputs correct value in specific field, kind of validation. If you want to make sure user enters correct value for each field then it will be difficult to handle it using single try catch block. You can try below logic, it will not allow user to move further till he entered correct input for a particular field. I have done it for Name field, similarly you can do it for rest of the fields :

```
boolean error=true;                        
Name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is your name?");                
if (!Name.matches("^[a-zA-Z ]*$")){
    error=true;
}        
while(error){                                
    Name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("You entered a number, this only accepts alphabetical letters. Please enter your name");
    if (Name.matches("^[a-zA-Z ]*$")){
         error=false;
    }                
}
```

Comment: This works somewhat I think I tried it out however it always seems to error on the start of the if statement even if the answer is a string